# How to output theory by using Aleph with SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog, aleph-ilp

I would like to use Aleph to get a theory with SWI-Prolog. My OS is MacOS 10.15.

Here is my input file:

```
% Aleph initialization
    :- aleph.

% Mode declarations
% mode(RecallNumber,PredicateMode).
% - output
:- modeh(*,grandparent(+person,+person)).
:- modeb(*,father(-person,-person)).

:-begin_bg.
person(john).
person(johnJunior).
person(johnJuniorJunior).
person(jack).
person(jackJunior).
person(jackJuniorJunior).
father(johnJunior, john).
father(johnJuniorJunior, johnJunior).
father(jackJunior, jack).
father(jackJuniorJunior, jackJunior).
:-end_bg.

:-begin_in_pos.
grandparent(john, johnJuniorJunior).
grandparent(jack, jackJuniorJunior).
:-end_in_pos.

:-begin_in_neg.
grandparent(jack, john).
:-end_in_neg.

:-aleph_read_all.
```

My steps are:

```
?- use_module(library(aleph)).
true.

?- consult(['/Users/scfang6/Desktop/test1.pl']).
true.
```

And how can I get the output theory?

Comment: You need to call, for instance, induce/1. ?- induce(P).

Comment: Kindly stop tagging these questions as `machine-learning` - they are not (removed).